# Typescript for change object properties name

Tags: angular, object, typescript

I have a problem about how to change object properties name.
I have a object like this:

---

```
description: "Human Resource Management Module"

id: 8

route: "/apps"

__children: Array(2)
```

---

How can i change `__children` properties name to `indexSearch`?

Comment: Not really a typescript issue but an IDE one. Right click and "Rename" should do the trick !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are looking for solution to change object properties programmatically. you can assign the value of old property(`__children`) to a new one(`indexSearch`) and then delete the old property.

```
obj['indexSearch'] = obj['__children'];
delete obj['__children'];
```

see the below example.

```js
var obj = {
  description: "Human Resource Management Module",
  id: 8,
  route: "/apps",
  __children: ['item1', 'item2']
};

console.log(obj)

obj['indexSearch'] = obj['__children'];
delete obj['__children'];

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: it is not working in typescipt..

Comment: @Ozmen Typescript uses static types. You have to define the old and new fields first in your type declearation.

Answer (score -3):

You can rename it like this, it's pretty simple:

[image]

You will have to use the keyboard, potentially the mouse as well.